# Google play suspend my app - Violation of section 4.3

Tags: android, google-play

My Recently uploaded android app suspended by google due to below reason.Actually my app retrieve user contacts and send server for contact sync , but we set the read contact agreement.I don't know why they again suspended my app ? Help is highly appreciable.

**REASON FOR REMOVA**L: Violation of section 4.3 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.
Please refer to the policy help article for more information.

We classify a user’s contacts as private and confidential information. Apps which upload a user’s contacts to a service without making this clear to the user and obtaining the user’s explicit consent are regarded as being in violation of section 4.3 of the DDA.

All violations are tracked. Serious or repeated violations of any nature will result in the termination of your developer account, and investigation and possible termination of related Google accounts. If your account is terminated, payments will cease and Google may recover the proceeds of any past sales and/or the cost of any associated fees (such as chargebacks and transaction fees) from you.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not ask google directly?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221861/violation-of-section-4-3-of-the-developer-distribution-agreement

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play terms of service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the message provided, I assume you are not explicitly telling the user, that you are uploading his contacts. Setting the read agreement only asks the user, to give you permission to read (and only read) his contacts, but does not give you permission to upload his data anywhere.

What google is telling you, is to add a section in your EULA where explicitly note, that the users contacts are uploaded to a service so you can sync data.